# Exchange Web Services 2010 / Autocomplete or Suggested Contacts

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to find a way to mimic the behaviour of Outlook 2010 (and earlier versions) of autocomplete. Of what I can find, the Autocomplete Cache is stored on a local file (.n2k-file). Also, there is a Suggested Contacts which also seems to be what I am looking for.
http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/outlook/outlook-2010-autocomplete-cache-and-suggested-contacts

Is there any way to do hook up to the Autocomplete cache or Suggested Contacts this using Exchange Web Services 1.2 API with C#? Does anybody know a code example or documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EWS Managed API to resolve names in the same way that Outlook Web App does (Outlook uses its own connection to Active Directory to resolve names).

This will allow you to find all the users that match "Joe" in the directory or in a contacts folder in the user's mailbox.

See the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg274399%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx#Y0).